# Equation of motion - choosing directions for the coordinate axis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, free-body-diagram

I'm not sure this equation is the right one if we invert the direction of the positive $y$-axis.

Am I right if we assume the positive direction of the $y$-axis downwards, that the correct equation of motion would be

$$m\ddot{y}=mg-{\frac{\rho A C}{2}\dot{y}^2}$$

as the spacecraft tries to land downwards?

Where would be the direction of acceleration due to the net force?

[image]

Comment: "Am I right if we assume the positive direction of the y−axis downwards", it is completely up to you. You can choose whatever coordinate system you want.

Comment: @Yashas So is the equation right?

Comment: Yes. As you have chosen the downward direction to be $+ve$, your equation is correct. $mg$ is acting in the downward direction, hence the $mg$ term is positive.

Comment: What if the system is decelerating not accelerating towards the ground? Because that's what space crafts do

Comment: For me, decelerating has a negative sign implicitly included. I would say that an object freefalling is decelerating at the rate of $-g$ if I use your convention. Generally, we tend to use decelerating to describe a situation where the speed is going down. I always prefer using the term 'accelerating'  when I am describing something quantitatively.

Comment: Your equation is not right. The diagram hints that you should consider the y-axis upward direction as the positive axis. So in this case, the signs on the right hand side will invert. You should use one set of directions for the whole problem.

Comment: @Yashas  Do not use the word *decelerate*!  It's meaning is ambiguous!  If you want to say *speed up* or *slow down*, use "speed up" and "slow down".  If you mean acceleration in the negative coordinate direction (which could be speeding up or slowing down) use "negative acceleration".   "Deceleration" is begging for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to decide which coordinate system you'd like to use.

In your case, you have chosen the downward direction of the y-axis to be the positive direction. Therefore, the sign of the $mg$ will be positive.

Since the $mg$ force is acting downwards, the term will be positive. The force which is acting upwards will be negative.

$m\ddot{y}=mg-{\frac{\rho A C}{2}\dot{y}^2}$

Your diagram however, hints that you should use the upward direction as the positive direction. In this case, the signs of the quantities will flip.

$m\ddot{y}={\frac{\rho A C}{2}\dot{y}^2} - mg$

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the original equation as presented in the OP is ill-formed.

A correct vector equation should not be affected by an arbitrary choice as to the positive direction for the vectors.

In the equation given, the LHS will change sign under such a change in the positive direction. A landing space ship that is slowing to a stop will have a numerically positive upward acceleration, or a numerically negative downward acceleration.

Likewise the acceleration of gravity (second term, RHS) will numerically change in sign.  If up is positive, $g=-9.8$: if down is positive, $g=9.8$

However, the drag term, with the **square** of the velocity, is always non-negative.  It does not switch signs, and the equation fails.

The inclusion of a unit vector in the drag term, with a direction **opposed** to the velocity, would make the equation correct...

Answer (score 0):

The correct form of the equation is

$$ m\ddot{y}=mg-{\frac{\rho A C}{2}|\dot{y}|\,\dot{y}} $$

or

$$ \begin{cases} 
  m\ddot{y}=mg-{\frac{\rho A C}{2}\dot{y}^2} & \dot{y}>0 \\
  m\ddot{y}=mg+{\frac{\rho A C}{2}\dot{y}^2} & \dot{y}<0 \\
\end{cases} $$

This is because air resistance *must* oppose the motion $\dot{y}$.